# Eventhandling with kotlin and butterknife

Tags: android, kotlin, butterknife

ButterKnife click annotation is not working after changing java to kotlin code.

```
@OnClick(R.id.btnlogin)
internal fun onLogin() {
    if (isValid) {
        getLoginAPi()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove `internal`?

Comment: I don't know anything about kotlin or butterknife, but I guess your isValid variable is false always. Paste more relevant code.

Comment: @ankush any error showing?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked that you connected ButterKnife correctly?
You should have these lines in your build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

//... other stuff

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {
   compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
   kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
}
```

Comment: after adding dependencies and change @Bind to @ BindView  Error:Annotation processor '' not found   ..try to fix but still...

Comment: I added info about plugins. Do you have them all? Have you checked version of your Dagger dependency?

Comment: I think generateStubs = true is not required when you are using 'kapt'

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possible issues with the code
But let's first start with setting up Butterknife properly

Make sure you have the following

**Top level build.gradle file**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha7'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.6.0"
}
```

**App level build.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

...

dependencies{
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
}
```

Once this is done, make sure that everything you need butterknife to access is  public, so change the function to

```
@OnClick(R.id.btnlogin)
fun onLogin() {
    if (isValid) {
        getLoginAPi()
    }
}
```

For @BindView make sure you have the following syntax

```
@BindView(R.id.editTextKg) @JvmField
var editTextKg: EditText? = null
```

This will work because the default visibility in Kotlin is public

Gnerating stubs as mentioned by @Gaket in his code is also recommended by most, but it works without that for me

Answer (score 0):

You should check your dependencies, more specifically, you should use `kapt` for the annotation processor:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
}
```